# Symfony 4, LoggerInterface, how display human readable multidimensionnal array?

Tags: symfony, logging, multidimensional-array, tail, symfony4

During programming, I use the linux command 'tail -f' for show in real time logs of my application. 
With Symfony 4, I use the usefull LoggerInterface for logs some variables, then I execute the linux command 'tail -f var/log/dev.log'.

But I don't find how I can display 'beautifully' multidimensional arrays variables (display arrays with newlines for each new key=>value)

I tried several ways :

```
$log->debug(print_r($foo,true));
$log->info(json_encode($foo));
$log->info(var_export($foo,true));

$log->debug("test",$foo);
$log->debug("test",array(print_r($foo,true)));
$log->info("test",array(json_encode($foo)));
$log->info("test",array(var_export($foo,true)));
```

But systematically, my 'tail -f' command shows the $foo array in only one line.

How can I display human readable multidimensional arrays ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use custom formatter for monolog. Store your arrays in log as json and format it an another resources, for example:

1. http://jsonprettyprint.com/
2. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
3. https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print

For show pretty arrays and information you can use logs visualizer: Kibana, Graylog, Sentry.